# What type of compiler can compile what kind of programming language?

Tags: compiler-construction, opencl, openmp

These are look like silly questions, but I want to clarify my doubts.

I know C-programming, its a programming language, for this I need a compiler like `turboc` or `turboc3` or `devc`++ and others. If I want to compile a `Java` program I need `JDK` and jre., but in linux, with the terminal we can compile all kind of programming languages.

1. How it is possible?
2. Now I want to compile `OpenCL` program, which compiler I need??, I know that we need OpenCL SDK according to GPU company. I want to write a CUDA program.
3. CUDA is a platform or programming language? if it is a programming language, then
4. Which compiler I need to compile a CUDA program?.
5. Are there any specifications to write CUDA program? I want to write OpenACC program.
6. What I need to write the program and what I need for compilation? I want to write OpenMP program.
7. What I need to write the program and what I need for compilation?

Comment: You need neither TurboC (which is horribly out of date) nor DevC++ (which is rubbish). Get yourself gcc (with Code::Blocksif you need an IDE) or Visual C Express.

Comment: Newlines exist for a reason: to be used.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information; I know that TurboC is out of date and DevC++ is rubbish, but what i want is not provided by your answer.. i want to know the other alternatives, i only mentioned about linux compiler (which is gcc).. my curiosity is to know about OpenCL and OpenACC(GPU Accelerators)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Linux has the GNU Compiler Collection (gcc) that supports many languages (even Java is partially supported)
- CUDA and OpenCL use C-like but customized programming languages and specs are available from the project websites. These compilers are part of they SDKs.
- OpenMP and OpenACC are a cross platform APIs. Libraries are available for several languages.
- Try to google first.
- Better to write one program at time.